# How do I fix Error Code 0xc0000374 in RawInputSharp Demo?

Tags: c#

I need to get the Data´s (X&Y values) of two different Mouses connected to one device.

I hope to get the Data via RawInputSharp (https://jstookey.com/arcade/rawmouse/) but the RawMouseDemo version in this Package is not working correctly. I get 3 different types of error codes:

1. Code -1073740940 (0xc0000374) this one is the most common…
2. Code -1073740791 (0xc0000409)
3. Code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'

and sometimes the Code runs perfectly.

I actually only need a variable in which the values are constantly written to process this further more.

I´m new to C# and do not fully understand the RawInputSharp library. Could someone please help me? Thanks.

Code used to get the errors:

```
    public RawMouseDemo()
    {
        //
        // Required for Windows Form Designer support
        //
        InitializeComponent();

        //
        // TODO: Add any constructor code after InitializeComponent call
        //

        //create and init
        _rmInput = new RawMouseInput();
        _rmInput.RegisterForWM_INPUT(this.Handle);

        UpdateControls();

    }

    protected const int WM_INPUT = 0x00FF;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        switch (m.Msg) {
            case WM_INPUT:
                //read in new mouse values.
                _rmInput.UpdateRawMouse(m.LParam);

                UpdateControls();
                break;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    protected void UpdateControls() {
        if(_rmInput.Mice.Count > 0) {
            RawMouse mouse1 = (RawMouse)_rmInput.Mice[0];
            _mouse1X.Text = mouse1.X.ToString();
            _mouse1Y.Text = mouse1.Y.ToString();
            _mouse1Z.Text = mouse1.Z.ToString();
            _mouse1Button1.Checked = mouse1.Buttons[0];
            _mouse1Button2.Checked = mouse1.Buttons[1];
            if(mouse1.Buttons.Length < 3) {
                _mouse1Button3.Enabled = false;
                _mouse1Z.Enabled = false;
            } else {
                _mouse1Button3.Checked = mouse1.Buttons[2];
            }
        } else {
            _mouse1X.Enabled = false;
            _mouse1Y.Enabled = false;
            _mouse1Z.Enabled = false;
            _mouse1Button1.Enabled = false;
            _mouse1Button2.Enabled = false;
            _mouse1Button3.Enabled = false;
        }

        if(_rmInput.Mice.Count > 1) {
            RawMouse mouse2 = (RawMouse)_rmInput.Mice[1];
            _mouse2X.Text = mouse2.X.ToString();
            _mouse2Y.Text = mouse2.Y.ToString();
            _mouse2Z.Text = mouse2.Z.ToString();
            _mouse2Button1.Checked = mouse2.Buttons[0];
            _mouse2Button2.Checked = mouse2.Buttons[1];
            if(mouse2.Buttons.Length < 3) {
                _mouse2Button3.Enabled = false;
                _mouse2Z.Enabled = false;
            } else {
                _mouse2Button3.Checked = mouse2.Buttons[2];
            }
        } else {
            _mouse2X.Enabled = false;
            _mouse2Y.Enabled = false;
            _mouse2Z.Enabled = false;
            _mouse2Button1.Enabled = false;
            _mouse2Button2.Enabled = false;
            _mouse2Button3.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
    {
        if( disposing )
        {
            if(components != null)
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose( disposing );
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this._mouse1X = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this._mouse1Y = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this._mouse1Z = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label6 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this._mouse2Z = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this._mouse2Y = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this._mouse2X = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this._mouse1Button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this._mouse1Button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this._mouse1Button3 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this._mouse2Button3 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this._mouse2Button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this._mouse2Button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this.label7 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // _mouse1X
        // 
        this._mouse1X.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(128, 16);
        this._mouse1X.Name = "_mouse1X";
        this._mouse1X.TabIndex = 0;
        this._mouse1X.Text = "";
        // 
        // _mouse1Y
        // 
        this._mouse1Y.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(128, 40);
        this._mouse1Y.Name = "_mouse1Y";
        this._mouse1Y.TabIndex = 1;
        this._mouse1Y.Text = "";
        // 
        // _mouse1Z
        // 
        this._mouse1Z.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(128, 64);
        this._mouse1Z.Name = "_mouse1Z";
        this._mouse1Z.TabIndex = 2;
        this._mouse1Z.Text = "";
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 16);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.TabIndex = 10;
        this.label1.Text = "Mouse 1 X";
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 40);
        this.label2.Name = "label2";
        this.label2.TabIndex = 11;
        this.label2.Text = "Mouse 1 Y";
        // 
        // label3
        // 
        this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 64);
        this.label3.Name = "label3";
        this.label3.TabIndex = 12;
        this.label3.Text = "Mouse 1 Z";
        // 
        // label4
        // 
        this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 144);
        this.label4.Name = "label4";
        this.label4.TabIndex = 18;
        this.label4.Text = "Mouse 2 Z";
        // 
        // label5
        // 
        this.label5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 120);
        this.label5.Name = "label5";
        this.label5.TabIndex = 17;
        this.label5.Text = "Mouse 2 Y";
        // 
        // label6
        // 
        this.label6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 96);
        this.label6.Name = "label6";
        this.label6.TabIndex = 16;
        this.label6.Text = "Mouse 2 X";
        // 
        // _mouse2Z
        // 
        this._mouse2Z.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(128, 144);
        this._mouse2Z.Name = "_mouse2Z";
        this._mouse2Z.TabIndex = 15;
        this._mouse2Z.Text = "";
        // 
        // _mouse2Y
        // 
        this._mouse2Y.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(128, 120);
        this._mouse2Y.Name = "_mouse2Y";
        this._mouse2Y.TabIndex = 14;
        this._mouse2Y.Text = "";
        // 
        // _mouse2X
        // 
        this._mouse2X.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(128, 96);
        this._mouse2X.Name = "_mouse2X";
        this._mouse2X.TabIndex = 13;
        this._mouse2X.Text = "";
        // 
        // _mouse1Button1
        // 
        this._mouse1Button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(248, 16);
        this._mouse1Button1.Name = "_mouse1Button1";
        this._mouse1Button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(72, 24);
        this._mouse1Button1.TabIndex = 19;
        this._mouse1Button1.Text = "Button 1";
        // 
        // _mouse1Button2
        // 
        this._mouse1Button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(248, 40);
        this._mouse1Button2.Name = "_mouse1Button2";
        this._mouse1Button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(72, 24);
        this._mouse1Button2.TabIndex = 20;
        this._mouse1Button2.Text = "Button 2";
        // 
        // _mouse1Button3
        // 
        this._mouse1Button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(248, 64);
        this._mouse1Button3.Name = "_mouse1Button3";
        this._mouse1Button3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(72, 24);
        this._mouse1Button3.TabIndex = 21;
        this._mouse1Button3.Text = "Button 3";
        // 
        // _mouse2Button3
        // 
        this._mouse2Button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(248, 144);
        this._mouse2Button3.Name = "_mouse2Button3";
        this._mouse2Button3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(72, 24);
        this._mouse2Button3.TabIndex = 24;
        this._mouse2Button3.Text = "Button 3";
        // 
        // _mouse2Button2
        // 
        this._mouse2Button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(248, 120);
        this._mouse2Button2.Name = "_mouse2Button2";
        this._mouse2Button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(72, 24);
        this._mouse2Button2.TabIndex = 23;
        this._mouse2Button2.Text = "Button 2";
        // 
        // _mouse2Button1
        // 
        this._mouse2Button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(248, 96);
        this._mouse2Button1.Name = "_mouse2Button1";
        this._mouse2Button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(72, 24);
        this._mouse2Button1.TabIndex = 22;
        this._mouse2Button1.Text = "Button 1";
        // 
        // label7
        // 
        this.label7.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(328, 8);
        this.label7.Name = "label7";
        this.label7.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(64, 16);
        this.label7.TabIndex = 25;
        this.label7.Text = "Click Area:";
        // 
        // RawMouseDemo
        // 
        this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 13);
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(520, 182);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label7);
        this.Controls.Add(this._mouse2Button3);
        this.Controls.Add(this._mouse2Button2);
        this.Controls.Add(this._mouse2Button1);
        this.Controls.Add(this._mouse1Button3);
        this.Controls.Add(this._mouse1Button2);
        this.Controls.Add(this._mouse1Button1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label4);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label5);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label6);
        this.Controls.Add(this._mouse2Z);
        this.Controls.Add(this._mouse2Y);
        this.Controls.Add(this._mouse2X);
        this.Controls.Add(this._mouse1Z);
        this.Controls.Add(this._mouse1Y);
        this.Controls.Add(this._mouse1X);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Name = "RawMouseDemo";
        this.Text = "RawMouseDemo";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new RawMouseDemo());            
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Which line throws the errors?

Comment: 0xc0000374 is quite nasty, memory corruption from bad pinvoke is the usual cause.  And yes, the structure declarations in RawInputStructDefs.cs have a *lot* of mistakes.  This was only ever tested in a 32-bit program, it is guaranteed to corrupt the heap in 64-bit mode.  Types like WPARAM, HWND, HANDLE are IntPtr, not uint.

Comment: What do I need to adjust in the RawInputStructDefs??